# Video mediaDevices.getUserMedia zoom is not working in iOS

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, mediadevices

I'm implementing [zxing-js](https://github.com/zxing-js/library) to scan QR Code.
My task is to enable zoom while using the camera. It works well in Chrome on Android devices, but when I try to use it on iOS it doesn't work.

Below is my code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(environment).then(async mediaStream => {
    document.querySelector('video').srcObject = mediaStream;

    await sleep(1000);

    const track = mediaStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    const capabilities = track.getCapabilities();
    const settings = track.getSettings();

    const input = document.querySelector('input[type="range"]');

    // Check whether zoom is supported or not.
    if (!('zoom' in capabilities)) {
        return $(log).html('Zoom is not supported by ' + track.label);
    }

    // Map zoom to a slider element.
    input.min = capabilities.zoom.min;
    input.max = capabilities.zoom.max;
    input.step = capabilities.zoom.step;
    input.value = settings.zoom;
    input.oninput = function(event) {
        track.applyConstraints({advanced: [ {zoom: event.target.value} ]});
    }
    input.hidden = false;
});
```

When I check inside the `capabilities` using iOS device, the `zoom` attribute is not on the list. Any ideas on how can I solve this problem?

Comment: I dont believe zoom is supported on iOS with getUserMedia with a MediaStream. Google have a polyfil but the github issues show not working on iOS

https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/imagecapture-polyfill

Comment: @Marcus Thank you for your explanation. I really hope iOS will support this getUserMedia zoom feature in the next update.

Answer (score 1):

Zoom is now supported as of iOS 17.

[Improvements to WebRTC add support for...exposing zoom in MediaTrackCapabilities...](https://webkit.org/blog/14445/webkit-features-in-safari-17-0/)

Comment: Does it have zoom out?